# How to move only the position of the parent object

Tags: transforms, parent

What is the best way to change my parental position after I've set up all of my parental relationships?

I am now disconnecting the relationship between the parent and the child, then fixing the position of the parent and setting up the relationship again.

But my method seems cumbersome.

There seems to be better manipulation.

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a different ways to do this.

In Armature there is an option to make bone don't inherit Rotation:

[image]

Animators like to use this option on head

In objects you can use `Copy location` instead of relationships. `Copy location` is a constraint, you can add it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or on constraint tab:

[image]